# Can't save file on server PHP

Tags: php, file-upload

```
$allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg", "jpeg" => "image/jpeg", "gif" => "image/gif", "png" => "image/png");
$filename = $img["name"];
$filetype = $img["type"];
$filesize = $img["size"];

//checking file extension
$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed))
    die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

$new_file_name = strtolower($img['tmp_name']); //rename file
$target_path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/images/";
move_uploaded_file($img["tmp_name"], $target_path . $new_file_name);
```

The file should be saved in my /images folder that it's located inside the root folder, but I can't figure out why it doesn't work, I'm pretty sure that the server receives the file, because I can get from PHP its filename and its temporary location (/tmp/php + some random characters)

Comment: Have you checked the server's log for errors? Are the permissions set properly to allow the file to be written to the folder?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` returns false on error. Check that.

Comment: @AlexHowansky yea it returns false, but i don't know how to set writing permissions correctly

Comment: error reporting, use that then show us what the error was

Answer (score 0):

```
Try This:-

    $allowed = array("jpg" => "image/jpg",
                        "jpeg" => "image/jpeg",
                        "gif" => "image/gif", 
                        "png" => "image/png"
                        );
        $filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];
        $type=$_FILES['file']['type'];
        $tmp_name  = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
        $size = $_FILES['file']['size'];

            //checking file extension
            $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(!array_key_exists($ext, $allowed))
                die("Error: Please select a valid file format.");

                $new_file_name = strtolower($tmp_name); //rename file
                $target_path = dirname(__FILE__) . "/images/";

            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $target_path.$filename);


            //in insert query use this $filename variable.
```

Comment: I can't. That snippet that I've posted belongs to a function called `uploadImage($img)`, If i require my php page with POST method, then there's something like: `if(isset($_FILES['img'])) {uploadImage($_FILES['img'];)}`

Comment: OK, So in that code snippet  you posted change these lines:-

$new_file_name = strtolower($img['name']); //rename file
$target_path = "images/";

Hope This Worked.